# get data from xampp sql server using html and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, xampp

I'm a complete beginner in `php` and I am working on a front end project where I have to create a hangman game based on 12 island names stored in a `mysql xampp server` . I have to get a `random` island from the database as an `unordered string` displayed in my html and guess which island it is . I have no idea how to implement this using `php` since I am a complete beginner but I have watched tutorials about how to send data from html forms to an sql server with php . I guess this is kinf of the opposite task .
I have written complete `html css and js` code about displaying my hangman game and I use a simple word to be displayed randomly via javascript and when you fill the `spaces` a `submit` button appears .

```js
function hangman(){
    var island = "Santorini"; //the given word that is supposed to be found 
    var t = document.createTextNode(shuffleWord(island))
    document.getElementById("hidden-word").appendChild(t);
    createSpaces(island);
    
    const inputLists = document.querySelectorAll("input");
    document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener('input', evt => {
          const showButton = [...inputLists].filter(ip => ip.value.trim() !== '').length === inputLists.length;
          document.getElementById('submitbtn').style.display = showButton ? 'block' : 'none';
      });
    });

}

function shuffleWord (word){
    var shuffledWord = '';
    word = word.split('');
    while (word.length > 0) {
      shuffledWord +=  word.splice(word.length * Math.random() << 0, 1);
    }
    return shuffledWord;
}


function createSpaces(text){
    for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
      var space = document.createElement("input");
      space.setAttribute("class" , "dash");
      document.getElementById("hangman-container").appendChild(space);
    }
}
```

```css
.transparent-box{
    border:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:15%;
    background-color:black;
    height:500px;
    width:70%;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.transparent-box p{
    color:white;  
    text-align:center;

}

.transparent-box h1{
    color:white;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    top:30px;
}


#hangman-container{
    position: relative;
    width:auto;
    top:30%;
    left:0%;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}


.dash{
    margin:0;
    padding:20px;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width:4%;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 5%;
    background-color: turquoise;
    color:red;
    font-size:40px;
}

.dash:focus{
    opacity:0.8;
}

#submitbtn{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:200%;
    left:80%;
    float:right; 
}
```

```html
<body onload=hangman()>
<div class="transparent-box" id="t-box">
    <p>Play here </p>
    <h1 id="hidden-word">The word is : </h1>
    <form id="hangman-container" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" class="hide" id="submitbtn">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

The problem is how to use php to get a random island name from my database and display it instead of sending a string via javascript .
I would appreciate your help with this . Thank you in advance .

Comment: I feel that's not a specific answer for your problem you need, that's a PHP quick course. Just Google "PHP get data from database" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE islands(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Insert the islands names there (add as many as you wish in place of the ...):

```
INSERT INTO islands(name) VALUES
("Santorini"),("Tassos"),...;
```

Now the following SELECT query will fetch one random island name from the DB:

```
SELECT name
FROM islands
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

In PHP you can execute the query like this:

```
// replace the words in uppercase with your actual credentials!
$link = @mysqli_connect('localhost','USERNAME','PASSWORD','DBNAME');
if(!$link){
    echo 'Error connecting to the DB';
    exit;
}
$sql = "SELECT name FROM islands ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = @mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if(!$result){
    echo 'There is an issue with the database';
    exit;
}
$row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
// This will give you the random island name (if they are inserted properly)
echo $row['name']??'No islands are inserted in the database yet';
```

Now to shuffle it, we can use str_shuffle() function. Finally your code may start to look like this:

```
<body onload=hangman()>
<div class="transparent-box" id="t-box">
    <p>Play here </p>
    <h1 id="hidden-word">The word is : 
    <?php
        // replace the words in uppercase with your actual credentials!
        $link = @mysqli_connect('localhost','USERNAME','PASSWORD','DBNAME');
        if(!$link){
            echo 'Error connecting to the DB';
            exit;
        }
        $sql = "SELECT name FROM islands ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        $result = @mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        if(!$result){
            echo 'There is an issue with the database';
            exit;
        }
        $row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo str_shuffle($row['name']);
    ?>
    </h1>
    <form id="hangman-container" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" class="hide" id="submitbtn">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Now you will need to adjust your JavaScript code of course.

Comment: and the php file is a new file I create and insert in my html file ? Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Let's say the file is called "hangman.php". You can insert regular HTML code inside it. At the exact place where you want to insert the random name, you can open a PHP tag with <?php and then after the PHP code close it with ?>. I will edit my answer a bit for cleaner example.

Comment: Hi again I managed to load the random island name in my page . However after modifying my js code it still loads my old js code before modification . I save my code with ctrl + S . Which could be the problem ? Maybe because I am running on localhost ?

Comment: Cache? Try CTRL+F5